# Can a div styled as display: inline(-block) contain child elements?

Tags: css

Can a div styled as display: inline(-block) contain child elements?

Comment: The `display` style of an element should not affect its ability to contain elements, or what kind of elements it can contain. Only empty elements can't contain other elements.

Comment: @BoltClock That's not entirely true, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3 which hints at the distinctions and seems to indicate that the CSS can *override* but is *discouraged*. I believe it is invalid to place a block (say, DIV) inside an inline (say, SPAN). This makes the question more interesting, and the guts of CSS need to be consulted :-)

Comment: @pst: Yes I was referring to the fact that you can't tell an inline element to `display: block` and expect it to contain a block-level element and validate.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It can even contain block elements (which I think is what you mean anyway).